# VSCode - GDB debug console shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

I'm working on C code, and I'm looking for option in debug mode to jump to specific line without executing the lines in between.
Currently if i want to do it the only option I've found is to write on debug console:
-exec tbreak *LineNumber*
-exec jump *LineNumber*

Those commands gives me the option to jump to every line on the function.
Is there a way to create some shortcut for this? that when I'm standing with the cursor on specific line I want it to execute the 2 commands above on debug console?

tried already to check in Google and asked also ChatGPT and didn't got and answer i'm looking for